# How to add values from table columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i have a table where i list different values. Now i want to add a total values to my table that counts the values from each column and adds it to a column with the total value. How do I do this? And is it possible to do this in a simple way in the view, or am I bound to do it in the model? Thanks for any help!

```
<div class="chart-data">
  <table>
    <caption>Data</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <% statistic.column_titles.each do |column| %>
          <th><%= column %></th>
        <% end %>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>      
      <% statistic.rows.each do |row| %>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><%= row.title %></th>
          <% row.data.each do |column| %>
            <td><%= column %></td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
          <------- Here i want to have the code that sums the values from the columns above to form the 'Total'
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution would be to maintain a variable that sums up the column, then use it for the total at the end.

Comment: Having s a problem with the scope doing this. I've tried               <% row.data.each do |column|%>                  <%= total = total + column %>
                    <td><%= total %></td> 
                    <% end %>but im getting total as nil doing this. Maybe is some kind of scope problem

Comment: Do you initialise total to 0 outside the loop? you could try, row.data.inject(:+) [ruby > 1.8.7] or row.data.inject(0) {|s,n| s+=n} [ruby >= 1.8.6, faster although less elegant.]

Comment: yes, since total at start would equal to nil and so nil + something should raise an error. just add a line above with <% total = 0 %>.

Comment: This worked great, thanks alot. I know I should probably move the logic to the model, but this solution works atleast :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
class Row < ActiveRecord::Base
  def total_spent
    sum(:data)
  end
end

<tbody>      
  <% @rows.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%= row.title %></th>
      <% row.data.each do |column| %>
        <td><%= column %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    <td><% row.total_spent %></td>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Assuming of course that row is a model you could move this logic inside the row model. You may cache the page as well if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I moved the logic to the Row model, but I have trouble implementing it properly in the view. You write @rows.each, does this make a difference? As it stands I must use statistic.rows or no table is shown at all. When I use statistic.rows, your logic in the model, and row.total_spent for some reason no table shows up at all. Could it be a scope issue perhaps? I guess that'd be the reason for using @rows, but it doesn't work for some reason. Hm.

Comment: In StatisticsController#index [or where ever this table is] add: `@rows = Row.all`

Answer (score 0):

If your data is the result of an ActiveRecord query against a database you could ask the database to do the work of summing all the columns. It would be one additional query but would run very quickly as that's something databases are designed to do.